# why are my xamarin labels displayed with opacity

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

i was playing with opacity on different elements earlier, now i'm just trying to display a basic solid label but for some reason its sill opaque, . opacity is not set and doesn't seem to be inherited from anything, so why are they still opaque?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="foo.MainPage">
             <!--BackgroundImageSource="tiledstripe.xml"-->

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="RootContent">

            <Label x:Name="debug" Text="EXAMPLE" FontSize="48" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Text="example2" FontSize="48"></Entry>

         </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project bit its still not working.

[image]

edit/answer: it seems as if i mistook the (lighter) default color of labels as being less opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the opacity, it is just a gray color. That is the default color of Android label (`TextView`) if you haven't set some other value (which you haven't done).

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.opacity?view=xamarin-forms)

> The opacity value. Default opacity is 1.0. Values will be clamped
>   between 0 and 1 on set.

Comment: opacity isn't being set anywhere, therefore it should be 1 (solid). it's clearly not though, it looks 0.5

Comment: if you mean "EXAMPLE" that is because the text color is not black

Comment: oh.. then why are the colors of "label" and "entry" different?, shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Android has different default colors for Entry and Label